# NEST API AUTH ERROR - authorization code not found/ios

Tags: nest-api

Here is the code using obj-c ..i am getting "authorization code not found" error but unable to resolve it. i tried couple of alternatives

Error:{"error":"oauth2_error","error_description":"authorization code not found"}

Case 1:
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?code=%@&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=authorization_code,code]];

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSError *error;



 NSURLResponse *response;

  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Case 2:
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=authorization_code&code=%@", code];

```
NSLog(@"Post -%@",post);

NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //tried ascii too

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token"]];

NSLog(@"url-%@",url);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

My steps:
1. Used LHOAuth2LoginViewController
2. Opens webview
3. user enters email/pwd to login to Nest
4. "Works with Nest" is prompted
5. User "Accepts"
6. Redirected to localhost
7. Intercepted to get "Authorization code"
8. Use NSUrlConnection to pass Auth code to get Auth Token
9. Getting oauth2_error: "authorization code not found"

Comment: Can you please send the query parameters in the post body and retry the request?

Comment: i have tried that too..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample [iOS-NestDK](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/ios-nestdk) project on Nest's developer website. Specifically, take a look at the NestAuthManager file and feel free to use it in your project.

Cheers,
Raymond

Comment: The sample doesn't help.  I get the same error when running the sample:  "Error retrieving authorization code"